# Does $\Bbb P (A | B ) = \Bbb P(A | C) \Bbb P(C|B)$?

Tags: probability

Confused about multiplying conditional probabilities.

Does $$\Bbb P (A | B ) = \Bbb P(A | C) \Bbb P(C|B)$$ hold true ever?

Comment: Why not look at the *definition* of $P(A\mid B)$? This would stop the confusion and yield the result immediately.

Comment: Does it "hold true **ever**"? Yes. For instance, if $A=B=C$ is an event with nonzero probability, then all three probabilities are equal to one, and $1\cdot1=1.$

Comment: Maybe Stan means "always" instead of "ever"? In that case, no.

Comment: @Bof You just need one of $A=C$ or $B=C$. $\;$ In the first case $P(A\mid B)= 1\cdot \mathsf P(A\mid B)$ and in the second $\mathsf P(A\mid B)=\mathsf P(A\mid B)\cdot 1$.

Comment: @CarlHeckman Sure. If you assume that Stan meant something completely different from what he said, you might as well assume that when I said "Yes" I meant "No". Me, I work from the default assumption that people mean what they say.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Well and good, but it only takes one example to prove an existential statement, and the question didn't seem interesting enough to look for all possible solutions.

Comment: @GrahamKemp "You just need" in the sense of "It suffices that"?

Comment: @Did Yes, just so.

Comment: @bof: I wasn't sure exactly what he said, so I asked for clarification. As the old joke goes, you know what happens when you assume ...

Comment: @CarlHeckman The way I see it, if I answer the question the guy **asked**, and it's not what he **meant** to ask, that's his problem and not mine. It's not like I'm getting **paid** to answer questions here. (I'm reminded of a [Robert Sheckley story](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/33854).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say:

$$\Bbb P (A | B ) = \Bbb P(A | B,C) \Bbb P(C|B)+ \Bbb P(A | B, C^c) \Bbb P(C^c|B)$$

Comment: Suppose there is a student who is late for class. She will be late to a random class by $X$ hours, uniformly distributed over the interval $[0,\theta]$. Suppose we assume the most she can be late is 1 hour and the least 0. Suppose the latest she arrives during the ﬁrst 5 classes is 30 minutes. I want to find $f(x_6 | x_1,...,x_5)$.   According to the solution set, I can write $f(x_6 | x_1,...,x_5) = \int f(x_6|\theta) f(\theta | x_1,...,x_5) d \theta$. Why? How does this fit with your explanation? In other words, I don't see a $\theta ^ c$ in this formula, so why are they equal?

Comment: Problem 3(c) Problem Statement: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/assignments/MIT18_05S14_ps6.pdf  Solutions:  http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/assignments/MIT18_05S14_ps6_solutions.pdf

Comment: @StanShunpike Your original question was a general statement about events with presumably positive probabilities while your second question was about the Bayesian  updating of a prior distribution with a likelihood.  There are two key points about the second question: one is that the distribution of $X$ or $X_6$ depends on the observations $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ only through the information they give about the parameter $\theta$; the second is that while my answer considers a sum involving $C$ and $C^c$, you have $\theta$ able to take a range of values so instead of a sum you have an integral.